# Animation effect in a QToolBox in pyqt5 and python

Tags: python, pyqt5

Is it possible to set an animation effect to QToolboxes? I have 1 toolbox with 2 pages and would like to animate the switching between both. (Slide up and down)
With currentIndex I just can switch between 0 and 1 so animation with QPropertyanimation is not possible.
Is there another way to do that?

Comment: It's not impossible, but tricky. QToolBox uses a main vertical layout that adds a private button and a QScrollArea (containing the actual child widget) for each new page. When switching pages the current scroll area is hidden and the new one is shown. You need to override `setCurrentIndex()` and `setCurrentWidget()`, add two animations (one for resizing the previous to a 0 height and the other to restore its geometry), but you also need to be *extremely* careful as the geometry of the tool box could change in the meantime and the animation *must* consider that.

Comment: Oh, ok. Sounds complicated. I will take a closer look at this later. I think my coding skills are not enough yet to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QToolBox uses a QVBoxLayout to show its contents, and adding a new item actually creates two widgets and adds them to that layout:

- a custom QAbstractButton used to display the title of each page and activate it;
- a QScrollArea that contains the actual widget;

One possibility is to create an animation that updates the *maximum* sizes of the previous and new items, but there's a problem: the button is connected to an internal function that eventually calls `setCurrentIndex()`, but since that's not a *virtual* function, it cannot be overridden, so it would be theoretically impossible to get mouse clicks and intercept.

Luckily, QToolBox provides a useful function that can help us: [`itemInserted()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbox.html#itemInserted) is called whenever a new item is added. By overriding that, we can not only get a reference to all the new widgets, but also disconnect the `clicked` signal of the button, and connect it to our own implementation of `setCurrentIndex`.

To simplify the animation process, I created a helper class that keeps references to the button, the scroll area and the actual widget, and provides functions that will control the height of the scroll area and properly configure it based on their current/future state.

Now, the animation works using a QVariantAnimation that interpolates from 0.0 to 1.0, and then uses that ratio to compute the proportion between the two widgets based on the *target* height. That height is computed starting from the current height of the tool box, then we subtract the size hint of the first button (and the layout spacings) multiplied by the number of pages. In that way we know, at any time, what would be the target height of the scroll area, even while resizing the window during the animation.
The function that updates that height is always called whenever items are added and removed, but also when the tool box is resized.

Special care is required for computing the sizes when the animation begins: by default, the layout bases its minimum size considering the minimum size hints of its widgets, and scroll areas always have a minimum height *hint* of 72 pixels. By default QToolBox immediately switches between pages by hiding the previous item and showing the new one, so the size hint is unchanged, but since we're going to show *two* scroll areas at the same time during the animation, that would force the tool box to increase its minimum size. The solution is to force the minimum size to 1 for both scroll areas, so that the `minimumSizeHint` will be ignored.
Also, since showing a widget adds a spacing, we need to decrease the size of the hiding scroll area by that amount until the new scroll area is taller than the spacing.

The only problem with all this is that to prevent too complex computations, clicking on another page during the animation has to be ignored, but if the animation is short enough, that shouldn't represent a big problem.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from functools import cached_property

class ToolBoxPage(QtCore.QObject):
    destroyed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, button, scrollArea):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = button
        self.scrollArea = scrollArea
        self.widget = scrollArea.widget()
        self.widget.destroyed.connect(self.destroyed)

    def beginHide(self, spacing):
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumHeight(1)
        # remove the layout spacing as showing the new widget will increment
        # the layout size hint requirement
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumHeight(self.scrollArea.height() - spacing)
        # force the scroll bar off if it's not visible before hiding
        if not self.scrollArea.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
            self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def beginShow(self, targetHeight):
        if self.scrollArea.widget().minimumSizeHint().height() <= targetHeight:
            # force the scroll bar off it will *probably* not required when the
            # widget will be shown
            self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        else:
            # the widget will need a scroll bar, but we don't know when;
            # we will show it anyway, even if it's a bit ugly
            self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
                QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumHeight(0)
        self.scrollArea.show()

    def setHeight(self, height):
        if height and not self.scrollArea.minimumHeight():
            # prevent the layout considering the minimumSizeHint
            self.scrollArea.setMinimumHeight(1)
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumHeight(height)

    def finalize(self):
        # reset the min/max height and the scroll bar policy
        self.scrollArea.setMinimumHeight(0)
        self.scrollArea.setMaximumHeight(16777215)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(
            QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAsNeeded)


class AnimatedToolBox(QtWidgets.QToolBox):
    _oldPage = _newPage = None
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._pages = []

    @cached_property
    def animation(self):
        animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(self)
        animation.setDuration(250)
        animation.setStartValue(0.)
        animation.setEndValue(1.)
        animation.valueChanged.connect(self._updateSizes)
        return animation

    @QtCore.pyqtProperty(int)
    def animationDuration(self):
        return self.animation.duration()

    @animationDuration.setter
    def animationDuration(self, duration):
        self.animation.setDuration(max(50, min(duration, 500)))

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, bool)
    def setCurrentIndex(self, index, now=False):
        if self.currentIndex() == index:
            return
        if now:
            if self.animation.state():
                self.animation.stop()
                self._pages[index].finalize()
            super().setCurrentIndex(index)
            return
        elif self.animation.state():
            return
        self._oldPage = self._pages[self.currentIndex()]
        self._oldPage.beginHide(self.layout().spacing())
        self._newPage = self._pages[index]
        self._newPage.beginShow(self._targetSize)
        self.animation.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QWidget)
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtWidgets.QWidget, bool)
    def setCurrentWidget(self, widget):
        for i, page in enumerate(self._pages):
            if page.widget == widget:
                self.setCurrentIndex(i)
                return

    def _index(self, page):
        return self._pages.index(page)

    def _updateSizes(self, ratio):
        if self.animation.currentTime() < self.animation.duration():
            newSize = round(self._targetSize * ratio)
            oldSize = self._targetSize - newSize
            if newSize < self.layout().spacing():
                oldSize -= self.layout().spacing()
            self._oldPage.setHeight(max(0, oldSize))
            self._newPage.setHeight(newSize)
        else:
            super().setCurrentIndex(self._index(self._newPage))
            self._oldPage.finalize()
            self._newPage.finalize()

    def _computeTargetSize(self):
        if not self.count():
            self._targetSize = 0
            return
        l, t, r, b = self.getContentsMargins()
        baseHeight = (self._pages[0].button.sizeHint().height()
            + self.layout().spacing())
        self._targetSize = self.height() - t - b - baseHeight * self.count()

    def _buttonClicked(self):
        button = self.sender()
        for i, page in enumerate(self._pages):
            if page.button == button:
                self.setCurrentIndex(i)
                return

    def _widgetDestroyed(self):
        self._pages.remove(self.sender())

    def itemInserted(self, index):
        button = self.layout().itemAt(index * 2).widget()
        button.clicked.disconnect()
        button.clicked.connect(self._buttonClicked)
        scrollArea = self.layout().itemAt(index * 2 + 1).widget()
        page = ToolBoxPage(button, scrollArea)
        self._pages.insert(index, page)
        page.destroyed.connect(self._widgetDestroyed)
        self._computeTargetSize()

    def itemRemoved(self, index):
        if self.animation.state() and self._index(self._newPage) == index:
            self.animation.stop()
        page = self._pages.pop(index)
        page.destroyed.disconnect(self._widgetDestroyed)
        self._computeTargetSize()

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super().resizeEvent(event)
        self._computeTargetSize()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    toolBox = AnimatedToolBox()
    for i in range(8):
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        for b in range((i + 1) * 2):
            layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button {}'.format(b + 1)))
        layout.addStretch()
        toolBox.addItem(container, 'Box {}'.format(i + 1))
    toolBox.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```